# Centering text in vertical progress bar (position absolute)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do something resembling health bar and I currently stuggle with centering the text within it. I exhausted my options, it was either off center when the text changed length or text goes outside the borders of bar.

Here's how it looks with my current CSS

http://prntscr.com/lr9l9c

```
.bar{
position: relative;
background: #1DA598;
height: 96px;
width: 16px;
border: 1px solid #333;
margin-top: 72px;
margin-left: 24px;
}

.barFiller{
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    transition: width .2s ease-in;
}

.barText{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: "white"
}
```

barFiller and barText are children of bar

setting margins on auto and bot top left right on 0 didnt help either. Any other options? It should be centered and be flexible as progress bar can go from 2 to 6 digits.

Comment: Why must you use position, isn't text-align enough?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lr9qze  sadly no

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `rotate` and `translate` for the css `transform` property like this

```css
.bar {
  border : 1px solid black;
  width : 20px;
  height : 100px;
  position : relative;
}

@keyframes health {
  0% {
    height : 0;
  }
  100% {
    height : 100%;
  }
}

.barFiller {
  animation: health 3s linear infinite;
  width : 100%;
  background : red;
  position : absolute;
  bottom : 0;
}

.barText {
  position : absolute;
  left : 50%;
  top : 50%;
  transform : translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  color: rgb(0, 255, 255); 
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="barFiller"></div>
  <div class="barText">Logan</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the exact pixels of the bar you might as well just use the correct pixel values instead of percentages.

```
.bar {
  position: relative;
  background: #1da598;
  height: 96px;
  width: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 72px;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.barFiller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  background: red;
}

.barText {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: white;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rgarcianuskin/pen/MzMVdo

Comment: Sadly, it doesnt work, try for yourself, change value of 90 to say 90657 and it goes outside the bar.

Comment: I see, if you are going variable numbers then you would do better to use javascript. As percentages won't really help you here either. The problem is that the element itself has a width that will vary. You could try using a negative margin in addition to the percentage but that again would require you to have a width.

Comment: I thought that would be an easy and quick feature, I think it's overkill to give it a lot of coding, I might just display the values above and below the progress bar for now in that case.

Comment: Flexbox or Table display would probably work better for you in this situation now that I think about it.

Comment: flexbox failed me initially, I will tinker with table display in the morning

Comment: You can try forking this. I was trying flexbox but I had one last problem to solve. https://codepen.io/rgarcianuskin/pen/MzMVdo

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.barText{
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 96px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: "white"
}
```